# convergence of nested recursive series

Tags: convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms, continued-fractions

Consider the recursive series

$ \; \ \quad \qquad a_1=0, \ a_i=a_{i-1}+b_{i-1}$

$ \; \ \quad \qquad b_1=1, \ b_i=b_{i-1}+2$

$ \ c_0 =0, \ c_1=4, \ c_i=a_ic_{i-2}+b_i c_{i-1}$

$d_0 =1, \ d_1=1, \ d_i=a_i d_{i-2}+b_i d_{i-1}$

What does the ratio $c_i/d_i$ converge to as $i \to \infty? $

Comment: Do you know how to solve non-homogeneous recurrence sequences?

Comment: $b_i=2i-1, a_i=(i-1)^2$.